# Converting if/else to case/when in ruby

Tags: ruby

I followed Ryan Bates' RC#386 - authorization. Ryan's original code is as follows:

```
module Permissions
  def self.permission_for(user)
    if user.nil?
      GuestPermission.new
    elsif user.is_admin?
      AdminPermission.new(user)
    else
      MemberPermission.new(user)
    end
  end
end
```

which works as expected.

I need to allow more than just three authorization schemes. I need to add additional authorization roles, such as `Editor`, `Moderator`, `Senior Editor`, etc. I am trying to do this by changing it to a `case`-statement. My code is:

```
module Permissions
  def self.permission_for(user)
    case user#.role  #TODO: This will eventually be refactored into a role checker...
    when user.is_admin?
       AdminPermission.new(user)
    when user.current_user
       MemberPermission.new(user)
    else
       GuestPermission.new
    end
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting a NoMethod error on

```
when user.is_admin?
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is because `user.is_admin?.===` is not defined.

Comment: @Sawa - `user.is_admin?` is defined.  All of Ryan Bates' code is working, and you can see where `elsif user.is_admin?` is included in the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chief advantage − and the *only* advantage if you ask me − of a `case`/`when` block is that the condition in the `case` will be run exactly once and once only.

So in this case:

```
case some_relatively_expensive_operation()
  when :foo
    # ...
  when :bar
    # ...
end
```

`some_relatively_expensive_operation` will be run once only, while in this case:

```
if some_relatively_expensive_operation() == :foo
  # ...
elsif some_relatively_expensive_operation() == :bar
  # ...
end
```

`some_relatively_expensive_operation()` will be run either once (if it's `:foo`) or twice (if it's something else).

This doesn't just matter for performance, it also makes the condition easier to change later on since you only have to do so once and not however many `if`/`elsif` blocks you have.

Obviously, this structure doesn't work at all if you want to test *multiple* conditions which are different − which is what your current code is doing. Yes, you can around this with a lambda, which another answer is doing, but this completely misses the point of this construct and is like driving in a nail with a  hammer.

So what you need to do is to add a method to object `user` is which returns a value with the role. I have no insight in your `User` model, but this could simple be:

```
class User

  # [..]

  def role
    if is_admin?
      :admin
    else
      :member
    end
  end
end
```

We still have to check for the special guest permission case, which can be done *before* the main `case`:

```
def self.permission_for(user)
  # No current user - return Guest permissions
  return GuestPermission.new unless user.current_user

  case user.role
    when :admin
      AdminPermission.new(user)
    when :member
      MemberPermission.new(user)
   end
end
```

Alternatively, you could modify `User.role` to return `:guest`. Whatever you prefer.

Now, you'll notice that these lines actually look very much the same. Why use a `case`/`when` block at all here? Can't we just construct the class name from `user.role`? Yes we can!

```
  # Get instance to the class
  klass = Object.const_get "#{user.role.to_s.capitalize}Permission"

  # And create it!
  klass.new user
```

And we can make a two-line method for this!

```
def self.permission_for(user)
  return GuestPermission.new unless user.current_user
  return Object.const_get("#{user.role.to_s.capitalize}Permission").new user
end
```

Or even one line if `User.role` returns `:guest` if there is no current user.

Comment: Isn't that what you want, is a branch that evaluates only once, and only on the value that you want parsed?

I am going to try and implement your refactoring, and if it works, I'll select as the best answer.  FYI - not disclosed, but I eventually will need to have each user have multiple roles across multiple projects/divisions.  I think that your solution is the best foundation for that.

Kuddos to all who responded, and in such a tijmely manner.  Gotta luv the Stack!

Comment: @Matteo "Multiple roles" is not something you mentioned earlier, implementing that could be as simple as a loop I suppose:  `user.roles.map { |role| Object.const_get("#{role.to_s.capitalize}Permission").new user }` but it would depend on the contents of the various `*Permission` classes...

Answer (score 2):

```
case user
when ->(u) { u.is_admin? } then AdminPermission.new(user)
when ->(u) { u.current_user } then MemberPermission.new(user)
else GuestPermission.new
end
```

or

```
case 
when user.is_admin? then AdminPermission.new(user)
when user.current_user then MemberPermission.new(user)
else GuestPermission.new
end
```

The former uses the [`Proc#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D), the latter is a perfectly valid case without initial condition.

Comment: I don't know why #2 isn't used more. It looks so much better, and is so much more economical of space, than `if/elsif/end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland exactly.

Comment: It's too bad `when` doesn't support the `&` operator, e.g. `when &:is_admin?`. That would make the first solution much nicer.

Comment: This code isn't better/faster/prettier than what the OP posted. A `case`/`when` is the wrong tool for the job here...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I suggest you to go read stackoverflow howtos. I answered the question stated in OP.

Comment: @Jordan yes, I’ve thinking about this many times. This example is not quite typical, though, and in this particular case there is always another better approach like mapping or whatever. In my experience `proc` is usually the only one out of several cases and therefore `&` is not _so_ urgently required.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement check equality to each when clause, for example

```
case x
   when 1
      puts "Do something when x === 1."
   when "D"
      puts "Do something when x === D."
   else
      puts "Doing nothing"
end
```

So for your example you'd want to keep the if/then style syntax OR do something like this:

```
case user.role
   when :guest
      #something
   when :admin
      #something
   #etc...
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case